# What effect does the donation box have?

Tags: dragon-age-2

In Dragon Age II there is a donation box in "Lirene's Fereldan Imports", where you can donate money to the Fereldan refugees.

Does this affect the game in any way?

Comment: I was hoping that this was going to be about some EA games Charity Drive where they pledged money to Tsunami relief for every X donated in game.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer You DO realize we're talking about 1. a business, and 2. EA, right? I find it really, really hard to believe a business, let alone EA, would donate money based on in-game virtual currency donations...

Comment: @Aeo There goes any chance we might have had of getting on EA's good side. :x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I tried for myself now.

Donating 5 sovereigns = 200 XP (outcome: 0.4 XP per silver)
Donating 1 sovereign = 100 XP (outcome: 1 XP per silver)
Donating 50 silver = 50 XP (outcome: 1 XP per silver)

As one can see, the payout for donating 5 sovereigns is worse than for the other two donations. But as you can only donate once, it may still be worth it, because XP are harder to gain than money.

Answer (score 4):

Donating 1 sovereign gives you 100 experience. It doesn't currently serve any other purpose.

Comment: Also, donating 5 sovereigns gives you 200 experience. I find that especially in the early game (act 1) there's so little to actually spend your money on that it's worth spending the relatively small amount of gold for a small amount of XP.